# expression not working

Tags: animation

I'm adding an expression in the location, and the object is static, not moving.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Which one of these expressions are you trying to implement, sin(frame*0.1) ? It should move your object.

Comment: OK, it's working now. I don't know why in the description they add the # and "". once I remove these symbols the expression is working. thank you.

Comment: You only need to put *#* when you first create the driver. When driver exists (magenta), it works the same but without *#*.

Comment: @blenderbreath This would have been hard to answer for us, since your screenshot does not show any quotation marks... but  why they should not do this? It's like in other documentations where somebody writes *now enter the password "1234" in the text field*, then they don't mean you should enter the digits with quotation marks...